# PHP array from jQuery .map-Function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a jQuery-function that passes a list of objects to my server via AJAX:

```
var pList = $(".post:not(#postF)").map(function() {
  return this.id;
});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "refresh",
        data: "pList="+pList,
...
```

on PHP-side, I need to check if a certain needle is in that array, I tried the following:

```
$pList = $_POST['pList'];

if(in_array('p82', $pList)){
    error_log('as');
}
```

which does not work, although "p82" is in the array. Maybe the jQuery object is not a real array or not passed to PHP as an array? Thanks for any help.

Comment: you cannot send array to php via ajax.. you will have to make it as json and send the json which you can jeson_decode on php side..

Comment: You can simply add `var_dump($_POST['pList']);` to your PHP script and then have a look what it outputs via  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network or Firebug. And yes, you need to serialize your list.

Comment: so "data: "pList="+JSON.stringify(pList)" and decoding it server-side should make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.get()` to the end of your map function:

```
var pList = $(".post:not(#postF)").map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

Then `stringify` the `pList` object:

```
data: 'pList=' + JSON.stringify(pList)
```

Decode the `json` server-side:

```
json_decode($_POST['pList']);
```